# Discord.py if message is a gif

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, gif

I want a function to run whenever a gif/image is posted in discord

```py
@bot.event()
async def on_message(message):
    if (message.type == discord.MessageType.gif):
        print("Gif")
```

I get

```
"packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 134, in on_message
    if (message.type == discord.MessageType.gif):
AttributeError: type object 'MessageType' has no attribute 'gif'
```

Comment: Supported `MessageType`s are listed in [the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.MessageType)

Answer (score 1):

`MessageType` does not have such attribute. You will need to try a differnt approach.
For example, you could check, if the message has (an) attachement(s) and if so, check if `.gif` is the file ending.

```
@bot.event()
async def on_message(message):
    if len(message.attachements) > 0:
        for attachement in message.attachements:
            if ".gif" in attachement.filename.lower():
                print("Gif")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add an additional answer, if it is specifically MEME's you're looking to isolate, the above solutions will not work, because they are not "attachments"

You'll need to look inside the message.content and look for "gif", similar to the above method.

```
@bot.event()
    async def on_message(message):
        if "gif" in message.content:
            #Do things if gif found, but this will also detecting someone typing gif
        if "http" in message.content:
            #do things but this will also prevent all hyperlinks.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Cleaner Solution

We can use python's regex module (`re`) to find URLs in Strings.

```
import re
def Find_URLs_in_String(string):
    regex = r"(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))"
    urls = re.findall(regex, string)
    return [x[0] for x in urls]
```

We can modify this code a bit to return only URL's ending with ".gif":

```
import re
def Find_URLs_in_String(string):
    regex = r"(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))"
    urls = re.findall(regex, string)
    return [x[0] for x in urls if (".gif" in x[0])]
```

Now we can create a Basic Discord Bot that utilizes this function:

```
import discord, re
from discord.ext import commands

def Find_URLs_in_String(string):
    regex = r"(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))"
    urls = re.findall(regex, string)
    return [x[0] for x in urls if (".gif" in x[0])]

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    urls = Find_URLs_in_String(message.content)
    if urls != []:
        # Gifs Found, Do Something...
        for url in urls:
            print(url)
    else:
        # No Gifs Found, Allow Bot to Process Command
        await bot.process_commands(message)

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

For more help with Regex - https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

For more help with discord.py - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Cheers, Eric